# C++ program hangs in Visual Studio v. 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've got a strange issue programming in C++.
I have to program in Visual Studio v. 6 under Windows 10 (a stupid requirement of a teacher at the university).
I have a simple "hello world" app which worked.
However, after running another C++ program other programs stopped working.
They get compiled and linked but they hang when I try to execute them.

I'm absolutely sure the "hello world" app is OK.

Visual Studio reports no errors, and there are no errors in the event log.
I've already tried creating the "hello world" app in a different folder.

Has anyone come across this issue, too?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the breakpoints? Add some print-lines and run the program from the CMD-prompt to see if it show anything.

Comment: Yes, I've removed all the breakpoints.
No, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Kill all running instances of VS6 and your apps, perhaps there are some zombie processes still running, thus preventing VS6 from working properly.  The EXE that did run, it didn't crash on exit?  You can check the event log for evidence of this.  This task feels a bit like a fools quest.

Comment: Oh, it's been a while...  Very important, don't forget to install the latest Service Pack for VS6, seriously.  I think there's a Service Pack 5 or 6, that might help.

Comment: I understand the description is silly. No, it didn't crush on exit, and there's nothing connected with it in the event log. And I've checked it after reboot when there were no zombie processes.

Comment: >No, it doesn't print anything. - Have you run the program without VS? Put an assert on the first row... Does it hit that assert?

Comment: Make an exclusion or disable anti-malware.  If it is Avast or ESET then get rid of it completely.

Comment: assert(1 == 2) failed!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, it turned out to be the anti-malware issue. After disabling it everything works.